# Is "qualified in" correct for the following sentence?

Tags: prepositions

> He is qualified in a variety of scientific fields.

Is "in" the right preposition for the sentence above?

Answer (score 1):

According to American corpus, it is correct.☺

http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=47569679

Comment: If you're on a COCA page, you can click on "history" near the top-right corner, just below your username. When the history shows up, make sure that you use a link under "SHARE LINK", not under the column "RE-RUN QUERY". (E.g., [habitual to/with](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=46996589))

Comment: Thank you. I am not a member of the web site. I mean, I tried to sign up, but it didn't rejecter me.

Comment: Thank you again. I tried a lot and finally, they registered me. now the link works.